# Combination of strings

Tags: python

I have a variable as follows:

```
symbols = ['KEL','BYCO']
```

I want a function that would give combination of these symbols as output as shown below

```
['KEL'],['BYCO'] and ['KEL','BYCO']
```

Could someone recommend any library/function through which I can achieve such combinations given a variable which contains n number of strings in it.

Comment: What you are looking for looks like a *powerset*. The empty list is also a combination... You can use `itertools.combinations`...

Comment: I have looked onto that function. In the itertools.combination(iterable,r) what would r be? In one instance I need it to be 1 to achieve first two elements of my output and then I need r to be 2 to get the last output. Hence it didn't worked for me.

Comment: well now you only need to increment the length and generate combinations of that length. Do you want to include the power-set?

Comment: Search for powerset in `https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.                                                                                                                                                                                                         
>>>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
>>> from itertools import combinations, chain                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
>>>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
>>> def powerset(iterable):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
...     "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"                                                                                                                                                                                                    
...     s = list(iterable)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
...     return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))                                                                                                                                                                                                
...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
>>> symbols = ['KEL','BYCO']
>>>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
>>> list(powerset(symbols))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
[(), ('KEL',), ('BYCO',), ('KEL', 'BYCO')]
```

The `powerset` function here is lifted straight from the documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html

Comment: Thanks. This is what I wanted.